# JS callback-promise combined pattern : good or bad practice?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, promise, callback

I'm writting some library that will provide asynchronous methods, I want the user to be able to use classic callbacks or modern promises depending on its own preference.

I was coding two versions of each methods by naming them 'myMethod' and 'myMethodPromise', then a thought came accross my mind :

**Why not coding a method that combines the two patterns?**

One single method with an optional callback argument, if not provided then the method returns a promise instead of calling the callback.

**Would it be a good practice?**

```js
// Promise-callback combined pattern method
function myAsyncMethod ( callback = null ) {
 if(callback) {
   var result = "xxx";
   // Do something...
  callback(result);
    } else {
     return(new Promise((res, rej) => {
        var result = "xxx";
        // Do something...
        res(result);
    }))
  }
}

// Usage with callback
myAsyncMethod((result)=>document.getElementById('callbackSpan').innerHTML = result);
// or with promise
myAsyncMethod().then((result) => document.getElementById('promiseSpan').innerHTML = result);
```

```html
<p>
Result with callback : <span id="callbackSpan"></span>
</p>
<p>
Result with promise : <span id="promiseSpan"></span>
</p>
```

**

Comment: To be honest, I don't really see a problem with this approach. But this might make your code harder to debug in the future for anyone who sees it. It's better to extract the patterns into different functions altogether, many libraries follow this pattern.

Comment: ok thank you, have any thoughts on the method naming ?

Comment: Except for backward compatibility with a previously designed and deployed interface, I would not build a new library with a combo callback/promise interface.  The present and future of Javascript is promises.  I would only offer promises in a new interface.  There is literally no reason for a new interface to not use promises.  If a client of your interface happened to be using an old JS platform, promises can even be used on any old version of Javascript (using a polyfill).  So, I wouldn't complicate my code or impact performance or maintenance or testing by offering both.

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow `request-promise` module. They have wrape `request module` inside `request-promise`. And as only written small config file to assign all promisable methods.**

More: https://github.com/request/request-promise/blob/master/lib/rp.js

**You can also use [node-promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)
to promisify method.**

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);
stat('.').then((stats) => {
  // Do something with `stats`
}).catch((error) => {
  // Handle the error.
});
```

// Request module

```
Bluebird.config({cancellation: true});

configure({
    request: request,
    PromiseImpl: Bluebird,
    expose: [
        'then',
        'catch',
        'finally',
        'cancel',
        'promise'
        // Would you like to expose more Bluebird methods? Try e.g. `rp(...).promise().tap(...)` first. `.promise()` returns the full-fledged Bluebird promise.
    ],
    constructorMixin: function (resolve, reject, onCancel) {
        var self = this;
        onCancel(function () {
            self.abort();
        });
    }
});

request.bindCLS = function RP$bindCLS() {
    throw new Error('CLS support was dropped. To get it back read: https://github.com/request/request-promise/wiki/Getting-Back-Support-for-Continuation-Local-Storage');
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to prevent the user from using third-party module to promisify my lib methods, plus I've seen that request-promise is deprecated

Comment: i m just suggesting u can follow same pattern. Not ask you to use. I have written, u can also use node `util.promisify` too instead of writing by onw.